# how to use phoenix5.0 with spark 3.0 preview

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

```
      case "phoenix" =>{
        outputStream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
          val spark=SparkSession.builder().config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
          val ds=spark.createDataFrame(rdd,Class.forName(settings.BEAN_CLASS))
          ds.write.
            format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").
            mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
            options(Map(
              "table" -> settings.OUTPUT_TABLENAME,
              "zkUrl" -> settings.ZK_URL,
              "zookeeper.znode.parent" -> settings.ZNODE_PARENT,
              "hbase.rootdir" -> settings.ROOT_DIR,
              "hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize" -> "0")).
            save()
        })
      }
```

it works with spark2.2 and phoenix-4.12.0-HBase-1.2, but doesn't work with spark3.0 preview and phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0, how to fix it?

Comment: Any solutions ? :/

Comment: @Nilesh no solution

Answer (score 0):

use phoenix5-spark3，but it is a snapshot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).